# Generic way to grep files including nth parent directories

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, grep

I was wondering that; is there a way to grep from nth predecessor directory?
For instance, let's say I have a script, which has grep command in it, sits under the given path:

```
/home/usr/project/utilities/wheremyscriptsits/myscript.sh
```

I want to start my grep procedure from this path:

```
/home/usr/project
```

Is there way to do this without explicitly indicating the path?
e.g. maxdepth like functionality for parent levels.

Thank you for your time and interest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, if I run `myscript.sh`, what do you want the grep to return?

Comment: it aims to grep "bugSet" from files that are under /home/usr/project.
I believe we may start with such approach: `echo ${PWD%/*/*}`

Comment: why don't you want to hardcode the path? why should your script be necessarily down in the file hierarchy?

Comment: Path may dynamically change. One may not be granted to do changes on higher directories, they may be protected...

Comment: *which has grep command* - can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but if I understand you then something like this will work for most cases with bash:

```
myDir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
startDir="$( cd "$myDir/../.." && pwd )"
find "$startDir" -type f -exec grep whatever {} +
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028 for more info.